# Firebase Realtime database serialization in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, serialization

I'm struggling a bit with getting data I push to Firebase Realtime DB in Flutter.

I'm using this code to push data to FB:

```
DatabaseReference newPostRef = news_dbRef.push();
        final newKey = news_dbRef.child('News').push().key;

newPostRef.set({
      "timestamp": timestamp,
      "content": content_u,
      "title": title_u,
      "imgURL": imageUrl_u.substring(0,imageUrl_u.lastIndexOf('?')),
      "fileURL": fileUrl_u.substring(0,fileUrl_u.lastIndexOf('?')),
      "user": _user
    });
```

so it creates a desired object in Firebase like this:

[screenshot from Firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBa7F.png)

Now when I'm trying to get this data to my app, I'm having issues with proper serialization with it.

This is what I'm doing:

```
DatabaseReference newsCountRef =
    FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child('News');
    newsCountRef.onValue.listen((DatabaseEvent event) {
      var data = event.snapshot.value;

      String encoded = jsonEncode(data);

Map<String, dynamic> postslist = jsonDecode(encoded);
var somelist = postslist.entries.map((e) => TestNewsModel(e.key, e.value)).toList();
```

so it brings me to a stage that I have a list... but cannot read values for each line.

Do you have any ideas what I'm missing? Here's a class I'm using for serialization:

```
class TestNewsModel {
  String recordid;
  dynamic fields;

  TestNewsModel(this.recordid, this.fields);

String toString() {
    return '{ ${this.recordid}, ${this.fields} }';
}
}

class Field {
  String timestamp;
  String content;
  String title;
  String imgURL;
  String fileURL;
  String user;

  Field({
    required this.timestamp,
    required this.content,
    required this.title,
    required this.imgURL,
    required this.fileURL,
    required this.user,
  });

  String toString() {
    return '{ ${this.timestamp}, ${this.content}, ${this.title}, ${this.imgURL}, ${this.fileURL}, ${this.user} }';

  }}
```

Comment: Any specific reason why you're calling `jsonEncoding` and then `jsonDecode` on the data from the snapshot before trying to create `TestNewsModel` objects out of it? I'd recommend setting a breakpoint on `String encoded = jsonEncode(data);`, running in a debugger, and checking what `data` looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Would recommend creating a .fromDoc method in your class, similar to how you would create a .fromJson method.

Heres an example from one of my projects, this way you can avoid encoding and decoding.

```
  ///Creates a [Patient] from the information from a single firestore doc.
  factory Patient.fromDoc(doc) {
    return Patient(
      doc.data()['email'],
      doc.data()['forename'],
      doc.data()['surname'],
      doc.data()['hospitalNum'].toString(),
      doc.id,
    );
  }
```